# Android SDK does not show the proper menu

Tags: android

I installed Manager on 2 PCs, and on the first one is everything ok, but on the other one I get this menu(the first image with HTC OpenSense and other crap is THE ONE I DONT WANT). How to fix it? I reinstalled it few times, didn't work.

First is wrong, second is ok.

[image: Wrong one]

[image: Good one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried reinstalling the SDK, did you just run the installer over and over again or did you uninstall the SDK first AND remove the .Android folder in your Windows user directory before reinstalling? If you haven't tried purging the SDK files from your machine first before reinstalling I suggest you try that.

Comment: I just used deinstaller, next time I will try to look for files in windows directory.
I have another question: I created an virtual machine 2.3.3 on AVD,and I have chosen a 128 MB SD card. Does it affects the speed of emulator? If i choose 8MB will it be faster? Cause it's like 25 minutes now and it is still turning on. The 1.6 booted up after 10 minutes, and second run wast fast.

Comment: I've never noticed any performance hits from using larger SD card files. My dev machine can start an AVD in about a minute and I've specified a 4GB sd card size. I can imagine however if your AVD instance was setup to load a number of things from the SD card it would slow things down. If you want to improve performance you can try turning off boot animation, increasing the amount ram available to the emulator, getting a faster machine,reducing the number of background operations running on your dev machine. Also if you're not already leaving your AVD running after it's started, you should.

Comment: Could not run the 2.3.3, but I started the Intel x86 API 10 and it started in few minutes but doesn't really responds(it is terribly slow - like minute to run menu). The 1.6 worked fine. If i reduce RAM of the device for example to 16 will it run faster? I just need it to simple app.

Comment: Could you give let say minimum - the fastest configuration for device with touch screen, sounds, and home/back buttons. I just want to do an easy text/one 3d animation app, no games etc. 
Does it diffs between 1.6 - 2.33 at this level of programming?

If I don't add in hardware touch screen will it by added by default or I have to add every single even obvious things?